# How to implement gradient descent for a tanh() activation function for a single layer perceptron?

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, perceptron

I am required to implement a simple perceptron based neural network for an image classification task, with a binary output and a single layer, however I am having difficulties. I have a few problems:

1. I am required to use a tanh() axtivation function, which has the range [-1, 1], however, my training labels are 1 and 0. Should I scale the activation function, or simply change 0 labels to -1?
2. So the gradient descent rule dictates that I shift the weights according to the rule:

$$
\Delta \omega = -\eta \frac{\delta E}{\delta \omega}
$$

I am using the mean square error for my error:

$$
E = (output - label)^2
$$

Considering my output is $o = tanh(\omega .x)$, x is my input vector and $y_i$ is the corresponding label here. 
$$
\frac{\delta E}{\delta \omega} = \frac{\delta (y_i - tanh(wx))^2}{\delta \omega} \\= -2(y_i - tanh(wx))(1 -tanh^2(wx)) \frac{\delta wx}{\delta w} \\= -2(y_i - tanh(wx))(1 -tanh^2(wx)) x \\= -2(y_i - o)(1 - o^2)x
$$

I implemented this is python, the dot product of the input vector with the weights turns out to be too large, which makes $tanh(x)=1$ and $1-o^2 = 0$, so I can't learn. How can I circumvent this problem?

Thanks for the replies.

The implementation:

```
def perc_nnet(X, y, iter = 10000, eta=0.0001):
    a, b, c = X.shape
    W_aug = np.random.normal(0, 0.01, a*b+1)
    errors = []

    for i in range(iter):
        selector = rd.randint(0,c-1)
        x_n = X[:,:,selector].ravel() #.append(1) #has the bias as well
        x_n = np.append(x_n, 1)
        v = x_n.dot(W_aug)
        o = np.tanh(v)
        y_i = y[:,selector] if y[:,selector]==1 else -1
        MSE = 0.5*(o - y_i)**2
        errors.append(MSE)
        delta = - eta * (o - y_i) * (1 - o**2) * x_n
        W_aug = W_aug + delta

    return W_aug, errors
```

Comment: Can you provide your Python implementation?

Comment: I updated the question with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I circumvent this problem?

**TLDR :** Normalize your input data.

**Why?**

Notice how tanh actually works on the input data:

`>>> np.tanh(np.asarray([-1000, -100, -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000])) 
array([-1. , -1., -1. , -0.76159416,  0.,0.76159416,  1. ,1.   , 1])`

If your data input to tanh has a magnitude of 10 or more, tanh produces an output of 1. That means it treats 10, 50, 100, 1000 the same. We don't want that.

This would explain

> the input vector with the weights turns out to be too large, which makes tanh(x)=1tanh(x)=1 and 1−o2=01−o2=0, so I can't learn.

Instead, we normalize the data (by dividing the input data by 1000 ( there are other ways of doing this)):

`>>> np.tanh(np.asarray([-1000, -100, -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000]) / 1000)
array([-0.76159416, -0.09966799, -0.00999967, -0.001, 0. ,0.001,  0.00999967,  0.09966799,  0.76159416])`

Now, tanh treats all of them differently.

**Note**
You are doing a classification task. Using mean squared error as a Cost Function won't yield the best results here. You should instead use Cross Entropy Loss with One Hot Vectors and softmax.

As to why should be a whole different answer.
[Here](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/why-you-should-use-cross-entropy-error-instead-of-classification-error-or-mean-squared-error-for-neural-network-classifier-training/) is a link for the same.

Comment: Ah, seems so obvious now, a rookie mistake. Thanks.